# Android GL memory in heap

Tags: android, webgl, adb, android-5.0-lollipop, heap-memory

When I run "adb shell dumpsys meminfo " on my Nexus 5 running Lollipop Im seeing a huge amount of memory is getting used in the Private Dirty PSS of 'GL' 
My app is a webview based app, but I am not running any webGL/openGL . After a few minutes clicking around in the app it will crash, but only on the Nexus 5 running Lollipop, with no Log messages indicating what happened. I suspect an OOM error is happening cause by the GL memory in heap but im not sure why that is happening, and why my other devices will run the app without this problem. My question is why is my heap so large on this device and what can I do to empty that heap space?

the GL heap space gets to be 177116 and the Total PSS 539058

Comment: is your app using 3rd party libs? Sounds like a bug in some code somewhere thats not compatible with the ART runtime maybe

Comment: yeah im using a lot of libraries. correct me if im wrong, but I thought ART was introduced in Kitkat. all of my devices are running at least 4.4, its only the one running Lollipop that fails

Comment: it was introduced but not compulsory, you had to go select it in the options menu. (sorry I meant 3rd party like phone gap tbh)